# "ElementClickInterceptedException" Error When Using "EC.element_to_be_clickable"

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to click an element using Selenium via Python and am receiving the `ElementClickInterceptedException` exception even when I am using:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]"))).click()
```

The output error is as follows:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="MuiBox-root css-ozrpcx">...</div> is not clickable at point (365, 53). Other element would receive the click: <div class="MuiBox-root css-rfuu2u">...</div>
```

Is there another viable way to fix this?

I attempted to use

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]"))).click()
```

to fix my problem and have the element be pressed only when it is available to be clicked, but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error/problem and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example